# What happens to the file if StreamWriter or XmlWriter is terminated abruptly?

Tags: xml, transactions, stream, large-files

My problem involves an XmlWriter appending elements to a large xml file. I've tested it by killing the process from task manager and the result is as expected - the last line is only partially written, the text in the element just ends and there are no closing tags. How can I make sure that the last element or the last few elements are either fully written or not, transaction style, in case of an outside event (system crash, shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

Write the file to a System temporary folder or any temporary location. Once file write is completed copy to the destination location using the system command.

Results:

i) If system abrupts while writing the file at temporary location, file only exists at temporary folder which can be removed once application gets restarted.

ii) If system crashes during a system copy, System handles to revert back or remove the incompletely copied file.

Hence the user would not find the incomplete file in destination folder.